# Front tzitzit in back?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol

I have noticed that sometimes people will be wearing their tallit as in the below image, with one of the front tzitziot thrown back. Why is this?

[image: front tzitzit in back]

Comment: Despite the fact that the photo is of me, I do not wear my tallit like that.

Comment: It seems likely to fall "back in place". Have you seen people consistently move one (particular?) corner back when it would fall down?

Comment: @NBZ, I have seen one better: people putting on their tallit for an aliyah and setting it like that.

Comment: You are from Frankfurt and where a Tallis with white stripes? Where is your family originally from?

Comment: @Yehoshua, my family's from Frankfurt. I personally have never been. Minhag Frankfurt doesn't actually specify that the stripes be black, fwiw.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe the white is minhag sefardi. In shulchan aruch harav it speaks about the stripes being l'zecher hatecheles (nighttime sky colour), but I'm not sure what the rema, which most Ashkenazim follow, says.

Comment: @user613, R' Hamburger of Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz does not say that there is any particular stripe colour associated with our mesorah, although in a schul where most wear black-striped tallitot, one should follow their example so as not to be poreish min hatzibbur.

Comment: I've had Yekkes claim that a white striped Tallis is for Yomim Noro'im. :-)

Comment: More to the point, somewhere on MY I've already written about having the 4 tzitzith on 4 sides - and it generated some feedback. No time to hunt, today.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, This is a problem for those who hold like the Mechaber. For those who hold like Rabbanei Ashkenaz, I don't see a particular issue, although this is not our customary way of levisha for a tallis.

Comment: BTW: The ציצית are supposed to hang over the side - unlike your back one.

Comment: @DannySchoemann יש אומרים.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't know if you resolved this question ultimately, but it is most likely related to some sort of effort to comply with the 'Atifah Gemurah' concept discussed in Shas and Poskim. For details, see Ohr Zaruah to Tzitzit or the notes of the Alter Rebbe to Seder l'vishat Tallit Gadol in the beginning of Siddur Tehillat HaShem.

Answer (score 2):

[S.A. O.Ch. 8 (4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.8.4?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) says,

> מחזיר שתי ציציות לפניו ושתים לאחוריו כדי שיהא מסובב במצות:
>
> One should return two of the fringes in front, and two behind, in
> order to be surrounded by the commandments.

M.B. (9) says that we make an “atoro” for the tallis so that the same two tzitzios are always at the front and the same two at the back.

So it seems that it is not correct to have three tzitzios at the back and the reason it is being done is unwitting ignorance of the halocho.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you ask about the halachic permissibility of doing this. (I don't THINK it's a problem, but I need to research).

There are just plain practical reasons for the tallit "fold". It is long, and in some cases, esp. while seated, the tzitzit are on the floor. I read the Torah, and my shul has some huge tallitot that I nickname "tablecloths". When I put them on, the tztzit are trailing behind me on the floor. If I didn't fold the tallit, everyone else and I would be walking on them.

Also, folding the tallit seems to reduce the chance of the whole tallit slipping off of you. I can't quite explain why that makes a difference (I'm a Ba'al Kri'ah, not a physicist!)

BTW - Nice pic. (It seems like your neighbor's snooping?) But, the back of the tallit seems too long, also, and it looks like it will take one "Oseh Shalom" to become "ta listless" :-)

Comment: [The picture is of himself.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50292/front-tzitzit-in-back?noredirect=1#comment132338_50292)

Comment: +1 for the BTW. I actually posed for the photo before taking off the tallit, I don't normally wear it like this. I never have a problem with this tallit, in fact, I prefer something of that length over say, a size 36 (36" from atarah to bottom)